# chromecast - get rid of the css for Red Overlay "SAMPLE"

Tags: android, css, chromecast

I debugged the css used with version 2 player.js  (0002/player.js) and found the css below for the RED Overlay i want to remove from my default receiver.

from player.css

```
#player[type="video"][state="idle"]:after {
  content: "SAMPLE";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  color: red;
}
```

As the default player.js cycles thru states [IDLE PLAY BUFFER] the red , transparent overlay, "SAMPLE" is displayed.

I want to get rid of that feature when i play my own mp4s.

So, I removed the offending css above and i hosted the new css file without the red sample.

I went to the dev console for "Google Cast SDK" and changed the custom style to the URL for my hosted CSS file.

I wait 4 hours.

I reboot the chromecast device.

I manually reload the window in the debugger console for the device.

And , i still see the old CSS with the red SAMPLE.

What do i have to change to get rid of that CSS on the player.js used with the default receiver?

Below is the html loaded in the debugger for the chromecast device by my android app.

```
<html><head>
    <title>Cast Media Player</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="0002/player.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="0002/player.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/receivers/f742e4109ea711e3a5e20800200c9a66/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/mediaplayer/0.3.0/media_player.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="player" class="gcpa" type="video" state="playing"><div class="background"></div><div class="gcpb" style=""><video style="background-image: none;" src="http://....0685/fade0569-bd5b-4cc2-a05d-85cb24860c56-20140430101403.mp4"></video><div class="logo"></div><div class="gcpr"></div><div class="splash"></div><div class="watermark"></div><div class="gcpc"></div><div class="gcpd"><div class="gcph"><div class="gcpg" style="background-image: url(http://.....ecb7c32-me1563624197.jpg);"></div><div class="gcpf"><div class="gcpi">the light the Divinity t</div><div class="gcpj"><div><span>robrowntree</span></div><div><span>the light the Divinity the absolute poise Aaron rumpled beds at morning </span></div></div></div></div><div class="gcpk"><span class="gcpl"></span><span class="gcpp">00:08</span><span class="gcpq">00:10</span><div class="gcpm"><div class="gcpn progressBar" style="width: 80%;"></div><div class="gcpo" style="left: 80%;"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="message"></div></div>
    <script>
      var playerDiv = document.querySelector("#player");
      new castplayer.CastPlayer(playerDiv).start();
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not clear what the issue is here. If you use the "Default Receiver" or your own Styled Receiver, there will be no SAMPLE watermark at all; if you use the receiver that CastVideos app is using, you'll see that big red watermarking (which you will not be able to remove).

Comment: thanks.  i extended the "CastVideos" android app from git and did NOT change the package. So on the dev console, i got my own app id but the package is still " com.goog.sample.cast.refplayer" . I can not figure out how to get it to use the "default receiver" instead of the one with css that has the watermarking?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the package name; you need to create your own Styled player with your own (or default) css and get a new "appId" and put that app id in the res/values/strings.xml instead of the app d that is there.

Answer (score 11):

If you use the applicationId "CC1AD845", then the SAMPLE is removed.

This is the default application ID and defined by constant [`CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastMediaControlIntent.html#constants).

Comment: My Problem is Solved by using CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID insted of CC1AD845